Компьютер не видит провод ethernet
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, пк не видит Ethernet и нет драйвера на сетевую карту в диспетчере устройств, на нижней панели и в сетевых адаптерах тоже нету ярлыка подключенного или отключенного адаптера.
Материнская плата Aorus b450 elite v2.
Случилось это после того как как положил системный блок на бок, вытянул видеокарту, отъехал на час , до этого интернет был и все работало нормально.Индикатор ether не горит
Мои действия:

перезагрузка пк;
перезагрузка роутера;
диагностика неполадок сети;
сброс биос программно и батарейкой;
поиск в биосе вкладки LAN подключение(ее не было, только была LAN support которую включил и не помогло);
звонок интернет провайдеру ( по их стороне все нормально)
установка драйверов с оф.сайта gygabite разных версий установка с перезагрузкой пк
замена LAN провода от роутера к пк, подключение LAN провода к ноутбуку
удаление всех драйверов из сетевых адаптеров в диспетечере устройств


Используешь сетевой адаптер на материнке? Вытащил видеокарту, потом что? Включил комп - нет сети, или вставил ту же видюху, или другую, потом включил? Смотрю, там есть пара укороченных слотов PCI. Если вдруг накрылся (???) встроенный адаптер, то можно поставить сетевую карточку.

Компоненты сетевого интерфейса стоят на материнской плате как раз под видеокартой, их можно случано повредить при вытаскивании или вставке видеокарты. Тогда можеть помочь только внешняя сетевая карта.

И, на всякий случай, в BIOS Setup смотри "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller".
Инструкция к плате
P. S. Вспомнил ещё одну важную вещь: нужно переустановить драйвер чипсета. Отсутствие этого драйвера или проблемы с ним могут быть причиной (кроме аппаратной неисправночти и настроек BIOS Setup) того, что ОС не видит какое-то аппаратное обеспечение. Если после снятия видюхи компьютер включался, то это однозначно должно было привести к изменениям системной конфигурации.

там нет никаких перемычек Фото

Ага, там микросхема и кварцевый резонатор стоит. Что-то где-то отпало. Тогда вставной адаптер. Это старое фото. или ты вытащил плату? Может, она на гарантии?

ПК друга, а фото нашел такой же платы, на ней все нормально, ничего не отпало, интернет был до этого а потом через час пропал с концами и даже не отображается в сети

Вспомнил ещё одну важную вещь: нужно переустановить драйвер чипсета. Отсутствие этого драйвера или проблемы с ним могут быть причиной (кроме аппаратной неисправночти и настроек BIOS Setup) того, что ОС не видит какое-то аппаратное обеспечение. Если после снятия видюхи компьютер включался, то это однозначно должно было привести к изменениям системной конфигурации.

Была замена rx580 на такую же, материнка gigabyte aorus, откуда лучше качать драйвер с гигабит или с аорус сайта?

Отсюда, убедитесь, что rev совпадает

Спасибо, проблема решилась путем вытянуть перемычку gbe lan под видеокартой и вставить обратно

Ага, там таки была перемычка. Ответ помог?

Да, помог, спасибо

Тогда можно отметить ответ как принятый.
